# Detect color and remove that color from image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, computer-vision, captcha

I have image with kind of light purple image in background and character in dark blue. My goal is to identify text from the image. So I'm trying to remove light purple color from background so that my image will be free of noise, but I can't find the exact color code for that image as it is somewhat different everywhere, so I'm not able to mask image. Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('capture.png')

im = im.convert('RGBA')
data = np.array(im)

rgb = data[:,:,:3]
color = [27, 49, 89]   # Original value to be mask
black = [0,0,0, 255]
white = [255,255,255,255]
mask = np.all(rgb == color, axis = -1)
data[mask] = black
data[np.logical_not(mask)] = white

new_im = Image.fromarray(data)
new_im.save('new_file.png')
```

So I thought if I can remove color in all particular color range like [R:0-20, G:0-20, B:80-100] maybe that'll will work. Can someone tell me how can i do that.

Any other suggestion to solve this problem will also be appreciated.

Comment: seems like you want to hack a site? if not don't know why you want to get an information that you already have?

Comment: @user1438644 lol no, It's my school project for Deep Learning course.

Comment: Most of the time you can threshold the image using one of the channels but it is hard to recommend an approach without seeing the image - how the volunteers willing to help you are supposed to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Why take an image and convert it to 4 channels then take the first 3? Why not convert it to 3 channels in the first place with `im = Image.open(...).convert('RGB')` ?

Comment: Kindly add your image. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there seems to be a distinguishable shade from the text and the background, color thresholding should work here. The idea is to convert the image to HSV format then use a lower and upper threshold to generate a binary segmented mask then bitwise-and to extract the text. Here's an implementation using Python OpenCV

---

Using this lower and upper threshold, we obtain this mask

```
lower = np.array([0, 120, 0])
upper = np.array([179, 255, 255])
```

[image]

Then we bitwise-and with the original image

[image]

Finally we threshold to get a binary image with the foreground text in black and the background in white

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Color threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
original = image.copy()
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 120, 0])
upper = np.array([179, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(original,original,mask=mask)
result[mask==0] = (255,255,255)

# Make text black and foreground white
result = cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
result = cv2.threshold(result, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

You can use this HSV color threshold script to determine the lower and upper thresholds

[image]

```
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

# Load in image
image = cv2.imread('1.png')

# Create a window
cv2.namedWindow('image')

# create trackbars for color change
cv2.createTrackbar('HMin','image',0,179,nothing) # Hue is from 0-179 for Opencv
cv2.createTrackbar('SMin','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('VMin','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('HMax','image',0,179,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('SMax','image',0,255,nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('VMax','image',0,255,nothing)

# Set default value for MAX HSV trackbars.
cv2.setTrackbarPos('HMax', 'image', 179)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('SMax', 'image', 255)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('VMax', 'image', 255)

# Initialize to check if HSV min/max value changes
hMin = sMin = vMin = hMax = sMax = vMax = 0
phMin = psMin = pvMin = phMax = psMax = pvMax = 0

output = image
wait_time = 33

while(1):

    # get current positions of all trackbars
    hMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('HMin','image')
    sMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('SMin','image')
    vMin = cv2.getTrackbarPos('VMin','image')

    hMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('HMax','image')
    sMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('SMax','image')
    vMax = cv2.getTrackbarPos('VMax','image')

    # Set minimum and max HSV values to display
    lower = np.array([hMin, sMin, vMin])
    upper = np.array([hMax, sMax, vMax])

    # Create HSV Image and threshold into a range.
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image, mask= mask)

    # Print if there is a change in HSV value
    if( (phMin != hMin) | (psMin != sMin) | (pvMin != vMin) | (phMax != hMax) | (psMax != sMax) | (pvMax != vMax) ):
        print("(hMin = %d , sMin = %d, vMin = %d), (hMax = %d , sMax = %d, vMax = %d)" % (hMin , sMin , vMin, hMax, sMax , vMax))
        phMin = hMin
        psMin = sMin
        pvMin = vMin
        phMax = hMax
        psMax = sMax
        pvMax = vMax

    # Display output image
    cv2.imshow('image',output)

    # Wait longer to prevent freeze for videos.
    if cv2.waitKey(wait_time) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: it's working like a gem. Thank you very much, you're genius

Comment: bdw can i convert black and white image to white and black? like with white background and black text

Comment: @VIBHUBAROT, convert the image to grayscale then use `cv2.bitwise_not()` or `image = 255 - image`

Comment: I think you're looking for thresholding the image, check the update

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using a pixel array. Pixel arrays are slow, but if speed isn't an issue, they could serve your needs without having to download any outside libraries. Also, pixel arrays are easy to understand.

```
import pygame
# -- You would load your image as a sprite here. --
# -- But let's create a demonstration sprite instead.--
#
usecolor = (46,12,187,255)       # Declare an example color.
sprite = pygame.Surface((10,10)) # Greate a surface. Let us call it a 'sprite'.
sprite.fill(usecolor)            # Fill the 'sprite' with our chosen color.
#
# -- Now process the image. --
array = pygame.PixelArray(sprite)   # Create a pixel array of the sprite, locking the sprite.
sample = array[5,5]                 # Sample the integer holding the color values of pixel [5,5]
                                    # We will feed this integer to pygame.Color()
sample_1 = sprite.get_at((5,5))     # Alternately, we can use the .get_at() method.
# Do the same for every pixel, creating a list (an array) of color values.
del array                           # Then delete the pixel array, unlocking the sprite.

m,r,g,b = pygame.Color(sample) # Note: m is for the alpha value (not used by .Color()) 

print("\n sample =",sample,"decoded by python.Color() to:")
print(" r >>",r)
print(" g >>",g)
print(" b >>",b)
print("\n or we could use .get_at()")
print(" sample_1 =",sample_1)
print()
exit()
```

Just test each r,g,b value to see if they fall within some desired range for each color component. Then copy each pixel over to a new surface, replacing all colors that fall within your range with your desired replacement color.

Or you could add, say 75 to each R,G,B color component (if color > 255: color = 255) before placing the pixel in the new image. This would have the effect of fading all colors towards white until the light color is gone. Then you could repeat the process subtracting 75 from each remaining pixel (with component values less than 255) to bring the colors forward again. I doubt any decent captcha is so easily defeated, but there you go.

Fun fun!